# Is sagemaker:CreatePresignedDomainUrl required to open jupyter in SageMaker notebook instance?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to avoid to use the managed policies `AmazonSageMakerReadOnly` and `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` because I only want the users to be able to start/stop their own notebook instance and to open jupyter in their instance.

So far the user role has the following permissions among others

```
...
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:StopNotebookInstance",
                "sagemaker:StartNotebookInstance",
                "sagemaker:CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/OwnerRole": "${aws:userid}"
                }
            }
        },
```

The policy does **not** have `sagemaker:CreatePresignedDomainUrl` but it has `sagemaker:CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl`, when the user with this policy click on `Open Jupyter` in the AWS Sagemaker console , it opens an url `https://xxxxxx.notebook.eu-north-1.sagemaker.aws/auth?authToken=xxxxx` but that url will return:

`403 Forbidden. Access to xxxxxx.notebook.eu-north-1.sagemaker.aws was denied. You don't have authorisation to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403`

As soon as I added `sagemaker:CreatePresignedDomainUrl` for resource `*` then the 403 error **was gone** and the user could open the jupyter notebook.

My question is **why is that needed**, and **what resource should I put** instead of `*`, the documentation mentions `arn:aws:sagemaker:regionXXX:account-idXXX:app/domain-id/userProfileNameXXXX/*` but I do not have any domain or user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreatePresignedDomainUrl` statement allows the role to launch a SageMaker Studio app (and hence the `domain-id/user-profile` ARN). Opening SageMaker notebook instance does not need the presigned domain url permission.

You'll need to make sure you're tagging the notebook with an OwnerRole key, with value = userid (not username). In addition, you'll need to use the `sagemaker:ResourceTag` (instead of `aws:ResourceTag`).

See the [service authorization page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsagemaker.html) for a complete list of actions and condition keys.

Comment: changing 'aws:ResourceTag` to `sagemake:ResourceTag` did the trick. But the service authorization page says that both are supported for `sagemaker:CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl`